# Convert string to variable object

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a string called `edos.desktop` to a variable containing a main function, it needs to be like this:

```
edos.desktop = {
    main: function() {
        . . .
    },
};
```

and I need to call the function like this:

```
var package = "edos.desktop";
. . .
package.main();
```

but how?

I tried to use the `window[package].main();` and this doesn't work!

I tested:

```
alert(window[package]);
```

and it shows undefined, and:

```
alert(window[package].main());
```

does not show the alert...

please help me!!!

...and I dont want APIs

Comment: `"edos.desktop"` is input? `edos.desktop = {
    main: function() {
        . . .
    },
}` is expected output? How is `package.main()` related to input and output?

Comment: Is this all in the same file ?

Comment: i   have a function that you need specify the ```package```

Comment: You want to transform a string to an object containing a function ? what should this function do ?

Comment: and ```package = "edos.desktop";```

Comment: this function ```edos.desktop.main()``` have one line that contains ```document.writeln("this is an app!!");```. and yes, i want transform a string in an object that contains various functions

Comment: If the requirement is `package.main()` why is `edos.desktop = {
    main: function() {
        . . .
    },
}` necessary?

Comment: ```package.main() = edos.desktop.main();```, ```package``` its a variable needed of a function

Comment: its like ```openApp(package)```

Comment: Still not following what you are trying to achieve, and why the procedure is necessary

Comment: my function calls one script of another directory and append him to the body... imediatly the function gets the string and calls the main in the specified package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have control over the string, you cold use `eval` and take `package` as string.

```js
var edos = {},
    package = "edos.desktop";

edos.desktop = { main: function() { console.log('main'); } };

eval(package).main();
```

Or take the window object and reduce the splitted name space.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path.split('.').reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object);
}
var edos = {},
    package = "edos.desktop";

edos.desktop = { main: function() { console.log('main'); } };

getValue(window, package).main();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval(), but depending on situations, there may be subtle bugs and security problems.

In my experience, smart and quick ways are troublemakers. I Suggest that you do something like this:

```
var package = "edos.desktop";

switch(package){
    case 'edos.desktop':
    console.log("calling edo.desktop.main...");
    edos.desktop.main();
    break;
    case 'Other case':
    ...
}
...
...
```

Comment: its like tis, but for every case: "a.b.c", i want to the function search any variable of type and calls a.b.c.main, if error: (console.log("error on package: "+ package))

Comment: "case package: { package.main() }" understand?

Comment: i just want compatibility